# How do you detect all devices attached to your wireless network?

Tags: c#, wireless

I want to be able to pick up devices connected to our wireless network.

Namely:
1) Someone connects to OUR wireless device using their phone
2) We detect a new device is on the network and pick up the MAC Address off the phone

Does anyone know how to do this using C# libraries or can point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

Comment: We are going to put our own wireless access points (hardware) in so going forward I think we have control over this for new deploys. However here at the office we have a few Linksys WAP200 point.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to write an Application which is going to Connect at you're Router.
You can do it in 2 ways 
     
1. Web Interface
     
2. Telnet Client

Using Web Interface `WebRequest` and `Regex` are you're friends where you can get from Router Connected Client's.
Or using Telnet Client where `Sockets` is you're friend in this case .
In both way's you can get any message you want and store them in a String where you can filter later .

Comment: Do you know of any resources/sites/forums that show anything on this? Been googling around and can't seem to find much.

Comment: You cant find an exact example but learn how to use all this Stuff ,try first to Filter a Local HTML ,use Regex in that case i think you can learn ,than try to use WebRequest .....step by step buddy

Comment: Good idea! Easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use a packet capture library like libpcap (.NET port is [SharpPcap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx) or [pcap-sharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcapsharp/)) and resolve the IPs on the network. You have to operate in [Promiscuous Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) (Known as [Monitor mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode) in WIFI terminology). Very few WIFI adapters provide this feature. If you can have a wired connection to router; it will be easier.

Comment: Scuse my ignorance on this... If a client connects to the network they will get assigned an IP address? Would I also be able to get their MAC address?  Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can get mac for ip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187894/how-do-i-obtain-the-physical-mac-address-of-an-ip-address-using-c

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at [Managed WiFi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Does this not look for wireless networks? I am not looking for wireless networks a want to know what clients are connecting to ours.