# How do you determine which adapter is used?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a need to figure out which adapter is used when a connection is created.  In other words, if I have multiple NIC cards (i.e. wireless, lan, etc) on my machine, which card is being used for the connection?

If anyone can point me in the right direction...

Comment: I've got no idea as to the answer, but it'll probably help seeing the code to create the connection. Also, is controlling the NIC the connection uses ok?

Comment: You are not going to be able to force your program to use a specfic connection.  You should be able to determine which connection it is based on if a particular adapter is active.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying active network interface in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359596/identifying-active-network-interface-in-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#

```
foreach(var nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces.Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationStatus.UP)
{
    if(nic.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
       //nic is attached to some form of network
    }
}
```

VB .NET

```
ForEach nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces.Where(Function(n) n.OperationalStatus = OperationStatus.UP)
    If nic.GetIsNetworkAvailable() Then
       //nic is attached to some form of network
    End If
Next
```

This will only test active working Network Interfaces that are connected to an active network.

Comment: As you note this only checks that the nic is attached to a network of some sort.  I believe that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359596/identifying-active-network-interface-in-net is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could map it by the MAC Address:

```
var nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var nic in nics)
{
    if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        var mac = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        if (mac == "your:connections:mac:address")
        {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

The *"your:connections:mac:address"* part you can figure out following this method, using the IP address of the *LocalEndPoint*.

[How do I obtain the physical (MAC) address of an IP address using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187894/how-do-i-obtain-the-physical-mac-address-of-an-ip-address-using-c)

It's not beautiful, but it could work.