# Get a machines MAC address on the local network from its IP in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip, port, mac-address

I am trying write a function that takes a single `IP address` as a parameter and queries that machine on my local network for it's `MAC address`.

I have seen many examples that get the local machine's own `MAC address`, however none (I've found) that seem to query a local network machine for it.

I know such a task is achievable as this [Wake on LAN scanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html) software scans the local IP range and returns MAC address/Hostname of all on machines.

Can anyone tell me where I'd get started trying to write a function to achieve this in C#? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

As per Marco Mp's comment below, have used ARP tables.
[arp class](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility.aspx)

Comment: Not sure if it works, but with a quick google search I found this library which should do the trick: [http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/post/ARP-Resolver-C-Class.aspx](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/post/ARP-Resolver-C-Class.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I believe I've read ARP tables to be inconsistent and was wondering if there was a way to 'ping' for the MAC address.

Comment: I **think** that if you do a regular ping (or otherwise try to contact) the IP address it will cause ARP tables to refresh (otherwise the network stack would not be able to contact the machine in the first place); of course this will (if at all) work only if the desired machine is online. I don't think you can get reliable results for offline IP addresses, specially if you have dynamically assigned IPs.

I'm not a network expert though, so I might be wrong (trying to think with you on the problem).

Comment: Thanks, ARP tables were the way to go. Had a bit of difficulty with the example in first comment so have posted alternative. Cheers

Comment: Try this nice and clean solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37155004/6229375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I obtain the physical (MAC) address of an IP address using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187894/how-do-i-obtain-the-physical-mac-address-of-an-ip-address-using-c)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As per Marco Mp's comment above, have used ARP tables. [arp class](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility.aspx)

Comment: 1.Your Question asks for "to get an IP and find MAC Address" and it demands ARP instead of RARP(get MAC and return IP/host which you are currently using).How you ended-up here?
2.The site you're referring is using wrong definiton of process(MAC to IP is RARP instead of ARP)...

Answer (score 24):

```
public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    string macAddress = string.Empty;
    System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pProcess.Start();
    string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
    if (substrings.Length >= 8)
    {
       macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2)) 
                + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6] 
                + "-" + substrings[7] + "-" 
                + substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
        return macAddress;
    }

    else
    {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

**Very late edit:**
In open souce project iSpy (https://github.com/ispysoftware/iSpy) they use this code, which is a little nicer

```
  public static void RefreshARP()
        {
            _arpList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _arpList.Clear();
            try
            {
                var arpStream = ExecuteCommandLine("arp", "-a");
                // Consume first three lines
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    arpStream.ReadLine();
                }
                // Read entries
                while (!arpStream.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = arpStream.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        line = line.Trim();
                        while (line.Contains("  "))
                        {
                            line = line.Replace("  ", " ");
                        }
                        var parts = line.Trim().Split(' ');

                        if (parts.Length == 3)
                        {
                            string ip = parts[0];
                            string mac = parts[1];
                            if (!_arpList.ContainsKey(ip))
                                _arpList.Add(ip, mac);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogExceptionToFile(ex, "ARP Table");
            }
            if (_arpList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var nd in List)
                {
                    string mac;
                    ARPList.TryGetValue(nd.IPAddress.ToString(), out mac);
                    nd.MAC = mac;    
                }
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/ispysoftware/iSpy/blob/master/Server/NetworkDeviceList.cs

**Update 2 even more late, but I think is best because it uses regex that checks better for exact matches.**

```
public string getMacByIp(string ip)
{
    var macIpPairs = GetAllMacAddressesAndIppairs();
    int index = macIpPairs.FindIndex(x => x.IpAddress == ip);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return macIpPairs[index].MacAddress.ToUpper();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public List<MacIpPair> GetAllMacAddressesAndIppairs()
{
    List<MacIpPair> mip = new List<MacIpPair>();
    System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a ";
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pProcess.Start();
    string cmdOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string pattern = @"(?<ip>([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4})\s*(?<mac>([a-f0-9]{2}-?){6})";

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(cmdOutput, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        mip.Add(new MacIpPair()
        {
            MacAddress = m.Groups["mac"].Value,
            IpAddress = m.Groups["ip"].Value
        });
    }

    return mip;
}
public struct MacIpPair
{
    public string MacAddress;
    public string IpAddress;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct ans .for the post instead of @Macro Mp answer .....why not this  selected as an answer?

Comment: Why it's not showing own PC MAC but finds all other?

Comment: @Khan probably because there is no need to store your own IP in the ARP table as you already know your own IP and MAC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp#answer-7661829

Comment: For parsing macOS specific arp output I changed regexp to:
(?<ip>([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4})[\)\(\s\w]*(?<mac>([a-f0-9]{1,2}[:-]?){6})

Comment: @ulmer-morozov I cannot answer this currently without a mac. However if you provide me with a sample output, I gladly write a new regexp for you.

Comment: example: router.asus.com (192.168.2.1) at 60:45:cb:93:26:ec on en0 ifscope [ethernet]

Comment: @ulmer-morozov quick solution: https://regex101.com/r/h1Y0EI/1

Comment: i also noticed that on macOS MAC address can contain hex with single symbol. don't shure why but this is the example: iphone (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

Comment: @ulmer-morozov because 0 is the same as 00

Comment: i understand, but that is not working with expression containing [a-f0-9]{2} this is why I changed it to [a-f0-9]{1,2}

Answer (score 11):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, [Out] byte[] pMacAddr, ref int PhyAddrLen);

try
{
    IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("XXX.XXX.XXX.XX");
    byte[] ab = new byte[6];
    int len = ab.Length, 
        r = SendARP((int)hostIPAddress.Address, 0, ab, ref len);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ab, 0, 6));
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

or with PC Name

```
try
      {
           Tempaddr = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("DESKTOP-xxxxxx");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
      byte[] ab = new byte[6];
      int len = ab.Length, r = SendARP((int)Tempaddr.AddressList[1].Address, 0, ab, ref len);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ab, 0, 6));
```

Comment: This is the best example for my current need.  This does have one drawback in that it assumes IPv4 only.  Also, in .Net Framework 4.7.2, IPAddress.Address is deprecated.  Use this as a replacement: uint ipAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(hostIPAddress.GetAddressBytes(), 0);  Again, this ASSUMES IPv4 and will not work with IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Just a better performing version of the accepted method.

```
    public string GetMacByIp( string ip )
    {
        var pairs = this.GetMacIpPairs();

        foreach( var pair in pairs )
        {
            if( pair.IpAddress == ip )
                return pair.MacAddress;
        }

        throw new Exception( $"Can't retrieve mac address from ip: {ip}" );
    }

    public IEnumerable<MacIpPair> GetMacIpPairs()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a ";
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pProcess.Start();

        string cmdOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string pattern = @"(?<ip>([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4})\s*(?<mac>([a-f0-9]{2}-?){6})";

        foreach( Match m in Regex.Matches( cmdOutput, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) )
        {
            yield return new MacIpPair()
            {
                MacAddress = m.Groups[ "mac" ].Value,
                IpAddress = m.Groups[ "ip" ].Value
            };
        }
    }

    public struct MacIpPair
    {
        public string MacAddress;
        public string IpAddress;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With SharpPCap, It will work on Windows & Linux

```
public string getMacAdress(string ip){
        LibPcapLiveDeviceList devices = LibPcapLiveDeviceList.Instance;//list all your network cards
        ARP arp = new ARP(devices[0]);//select the first network card by default
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        PhysicalAddress macAdress = arp.Resolve(ip);
        return macAdress.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and created a small MIT-licensed library called [ArpLookup](https://github.com/georg-jung/ArpLookup) ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArpLookup/)) to solve this task.

It:

- doesn't create any system processes
- doesn't parse some CLI tool's output
- works on Windows and Linux
- provides an `Async` variant on Linux (it does on Windows too but it can not be truly async there)
- is free and open sopurce

After `dotnet add package ArpLookup` usage is as simple as

```cs
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using ArpLookup;

// ...

PhysicalAddress mac = Arp.Lookup(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"));

PhysicalAddress mac = await Arp.LookupAsync(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"));
```